# How to detect in assembly 8085 that the Auxiliary carry is 1

Tags: assembly, 8085

I am trying to make a little program that adds two numbers in bcd and I cannot use the DAA command. How can I detect that the Auxiliary Carry is one?

Comment: `lahf` or `pushf` and examine the appropriate bit?

Comment: I am new in 8085. lahf loads every bit of LAHF copies the five 8080/8085 flags (Sign, Zero, Auxiliary Carry,Parity, and Carry) I will try it thank you

Comment: Can you please give an example?

Comment: I did PUSH PSW, POP D and I got my registers D,E loaded with the program status word. Thank you.

Comment: @Jester -  I'm thinking 8080 or 8085 don't have LAHF, and that LAHF was added to 8086 instruction set to make automated conversion of 8080 code to 8086 code simpler. themis already figured that push psw, pop d worked.

Comment: @rcgldr yeah right, I misread the 8085

Comment: I did PUSH PSW
POP D
MOV A,E
ANI 10 to check the AC value. It looks good. Thank you